# Wordpress theme causing high server load

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme that I edited causing very high load on my server,

First i used this code to get only text from content

```
        $response = get_the_content();
        $content = $response;
        $content = preg_replace("/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/", "", $content);
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

Then i wanted to fetch all images inside my post content so i used "DOMDocument" Code:

```
            $document = new DOMDocument();
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $document->loadHTML($response);
            libxml_clear_errors();
            $images = array();
            $imgsq = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

I have every post contains a static part than is in all photo pages so i used that code to get it

```
function findit($mytext,$starttag,$endtag)  {

              $posLeft = stripos($mytext,$starttag)+strlen($starttag);
              $posRight = stripos($mytext,$endtag,$posLeft+1);
              return substr($mytext,$posLeft,$posRight-$posLeft);

          }

            $project = @findit($content , '-projectinfostart-' , '-projectinfoend-');
            $check = str_replace('ializer-buttons clearfix">', '', $project);

              if($project != $check) $project = '';

              $replace = array('-projectinfostart-' , '-projectinfoend-' , $project ,  '<p>&nbsp;</p>');
             $content = str_replace( $replace, '', $content);
```

Then at last i wanted to get all photos in thumb size so i used that code:

```
  foreach($imgsq as $key => $img) :
                   // Extract what we want
                      $image = array('src' => $img->getAttribute('src') );

                  if( ! $image['src'])
                     continue;

                if($key == $page) :
                     echo '<center><img style="height: auto !important;max-height:450px;" class="responsiveMe" src=" ' . $image['src'] . '" /> ';
                 endif;
                   $srcs[$key] = array();
                   $srcs[$key]['src'] =  wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_attachment_id_by_url($image['src']));
                   $srcs[$key]['full'] = $image['src'];

                if(!empty($project)) $description = '<p>' . $project . '</p>';
                else $description = '';
```

endforeach;

My server is 16 GB Ram and can't work with 1500 online users on single post page ! any ideas about what is causing this high load ?

Thanks.

Comment: XDebug for profiling. But `DOMDocument` and  `preg_replace` are my suspects

Comment: just how many images does one of your pages contain? e.g. average of 20 pictures = 20 calls to wp_get_attachment = 20 hits on the database * 1500 users = 30,000 queries overall. and that's just for pictures, not including however many OTHER queries are needed for the page itself.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, each post contains about 20 pictures , so any solutions i can do to avoid this high number of queries?

Comment: does all of this processing have to be done "live"? It's one thing to have to fetch information on 20 images. it's another thing entirely to fetch the SAME information every single time. if the page/image data doesn't change often, you should be cacheing the resulting html so you don't have to run any of the queries again for the life of the cache entry.

Comment: @MarcB do you suggest a wordpress caching plugin that would fix that problem for me i tested a plugin but i still had the same problem.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the above processing? Do you have an online example?

Comment: @bobdye [link](http://goo.gl/jIrj9Y) i think MarcB is right.